# Laravel PHPunit test: 'testUser' does not match expected type "object"

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I have the following test :

```
class AdminPanelTest extends TestCase
{
    public function photoUpload()
    {
        $user = new App\User;
        $user->username = "testUser";
        $user->email = "testUser@hotmail.com";
        $user->password = bcrypt("testUser");
        $user->photo_url = "abc.jpg";
        $user->save();

        $test = App\User::where('username','=','testUser');
        $this->assertEquals($test,'testUser');
        $this->assertCount(1,$test);
    }
}
```

The result says that `'testUser' does not match expected type "object".`.

The user is added to the database.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: yea you are missing the part about how you have to name test methods or use annotations via phpunit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your function to begin with "test"

```
public function testPhotoUpload()
```

---

`App\User::where('username','=','testUser')` is returning an Object, but you're expecting it to return just a username string `'testUser'` so it's failing your tests.

I'm unfamiliar with your `App\User` class, but just guessing from convention, it's probably going to have a property named something like `username`

In that case, then I would expect your test to pass if you compared those values instead, i.e. the expected string literal `'testUser'` and the object property `$test->username`

Also, `assertEquals` by convention wants you to put your expected value as the first parameter, and the actual value as the second parameter.

```
$this->assertEquals('testUser', $test->username);
```

Comment: Ok yeah i got that one, I have updated the question, Please have a look.